# How can I setup SSL support for a naked domain on AWS using the AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, aws-certificate-manager

*(StackOverflow won't let me use "mydomain.com" as an example so I have to use the real domain--sorry all but I tried to not make this an ad)*

---

So I've generated an SSL certificate for *.fantasyadsnetwork.com through AWS Certificate Manager and created a load balancer that can receive www.fantasyadsnetwork.com traffic (http & https) and that portion works great.

The issue I am running into is handling users who key in "https://fantasyadsnetwork.com" into the browser.  Note the lack of www (naked domain.) As it stands they are presented with an error message like:

[image: Screenshot]

The exact messaging is browser dependant.  If you add an exception, click ignore, etc then the user loads the site (which detects the lack of www & redirects the user to https://www.fantasyadsnetwork.com/) just fine but that is an ugly hurdle for a user to jump through.

Any suggestions on how to work around this?  Preferably without having to buy a separate SSL certificate from GoDaddy or someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I found my own answer:

When you are setting up the certificate in AWS Certificate Manager if you enter a single ***.fantasyadsnetwork.com** domain it will not support the naked domain.  However they allow you to enter multiple domains so just include the naked domain as well.  The bad news is you can't edit this after you've created the certificate so you'll need to create a new one.

[image]